# jQuery Crypted Parameter String

Tags: jquery

I just found a website using 1 string as a data parameter. This string is crypted and contains other parameters which will be used in the JavaScript section of the website.

Example:

```
index?data=Q7aOgwzkG9a8YK0v7wJigerA7ZCmmBj5s8flxjbDC3SzbsQwfSrTXgxHUqhpbUkcpcDmTzf9RRPZLnw8iD9aWKeT4/cToZtNW1Lqys7pPX1kSEaPGA5YvTGlneUNTLyGJ2YYgoNuP/wxsQOT17l/EXNxiAodhZ6rfS+O1lq8ly5rEniftC7/PA==
```

The parameter data can be splitted into several parts:

```
Q7aOgwzkG9a8YK0v7wJigerA7ZCmmBj5s8flxjbDC3SzbsQwfSrTXg
xHUqhpbUkcpcDmTzf9RRP
ZLnw8iD9aW
KeT4/cToZtN
W1Lqys7pPX1kSEaPGA5YvTGlneUNTLyGJ2YYgoNuP/wxsQOT17l/E
XNxiAodhZ6rfS+O1lq8ly5rEniftC7/PA==
```

These parts are repeating itself:

```
Q7aOgwzkG9a8YK0v7wJigerA7ZCmmBj5s8flxjbDC3SzbsQwfSrTXg
ZLnw8iD9aW
W1Lqys7pPX1kSEaPGA5YvTGlneUNTLyGJ2YYgoNuP/wxsQOT17l/E
```

I really like that way of crypting your parameters - but I don't have clue on how to do it. I already send a mail to their site and was asking but didn't got a reply - so maybe you can help me here to push me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't "encrypted" it's just base64 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). I think it shouldn't be splitted... this will cause a crash in the decoder.

The given code ... it's result ... don't tell me anything, just try it yourself (http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/)

There are some base64-en-/decoder for javascript available, so you can use anyone you want.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) - Unfortunately it all seems rubbish to me since the decoder just puts out a binary file, so I guess this can't be right either or am I wrong?

Comment: You're right. I got a binary, too. Maybe you've interpreted the usage incorrect.
Sometimes I used binary data in JS, but only for viewing images or audios manipulated directly with JS. The kind of this binary ... well I don't know, sry.

Comment: No I'm pretty sure it contains an array with parameters in it :-7 Nevertheless - thank you :) Hopefully someone else will have an idea